# PhantomJS process doesn't exit when called from shell_exec

Tags: php, phantomjs

I am executing phantomjs command to take a screenshot for a web site through php's `shell_exec` but even after the screenshot is taken the process doesn't exit.

I am executing PhantomJS through [capturejs](https://github.com/superbrothers/capturejs) like this:

```
capturejs --ignore-ssl-errors yes --uri "google.com" -o "test.png" --viewportsize 1280x800
```

The capturejs code does call `phantom.exit()` after the screenshot has been taken.

Note: I am taking screenshot for google so there are no syntax errors.